# Google Events and Contacts not Showing Up in Outlook

Tags: sync, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, google-calendar, outlook

I own a Nexus 5. I have an Office 365 email account that I use to run my small business. When using KitKat, if I entered a contact or calendar appointment in the contact/calendar app that I was using, it would automatically show up in Outlook and Outlook appointments would show up on my phone. Since the download of Lollipop, appointments and contacts entered into Outlook show up on my phone, but appointments entered on my phone (as "events"), and contacts, don't show up in Outlook. As my staff has to be able to book me appointments and see my availability to do so and I am on the road a lot, this is a serious negative.

I cannot see how to change the appointment/contact creation mechanism to the exchange account on my phone. Anybody out there who can help?!